# How to set a preceding function parameter to its default in c++?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, default

Apologies if this basic question has already been answered. What would I put inside the brackets of `print()` so that the first parameter is left to the default value but the following parameters are given new values of 1 and 2? I know I can literally put 0 in there but is there a way for it go to a default?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void printer(int a=0, int b=0, int c=0){
 cout << a << endl;
 cout << b << endl;
 cout << c << endl;
}

int main(){

//leave a=0 and replace both b and c 
printer(/*?*/,1,2);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anything wrong with overloading `printer()`? `void printer(int b=0, int c=0)` and declare `int a` inside the function?

Comment: add the above comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that, it's not allowed. Only right most parameters could be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Default parameter list is right associative. So its not possible to ommit first parameter list.

Answer (score 2):

all parameters after first default are default. You can get what you want in this particular case changing the sequence:

```
void printer(int b=0, int c=0,int a=0){
 cout << a << endl;
 cout << b << endl;
 cout << c << endl;
}

//leave a=0 and replace both b and c 
printer(1,2);
```

> output:
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::placeholders::N`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) to delegate the arguments to specify to the returned function object from [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

```
int main()
{
   auto f = std::bind(printer, 0, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

   f(4, 5);
}
```

[***Live Demo***](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%243975)

Comment: Unless `f` is going to be used often, this might be a little overkill!

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize **function overloading** to achieve what you want:

```
void printer(int a, int b, int c) {
  cout << a << endl;
  cout << b << endl;
  cout << c << endl;
}

void printer() {
  printer(0, 0, 0);
}

void printer(int b = 0, int c = 0) {
  printer(0, b, c);
}

int main(){
  // leave a = 0 and replace both b and c 
  printer(1, 2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Any call to `printer` with less than three arguments is ambiguous, because both versions match the argument list.

Comment: Updated the answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly that, but one approach to this problem is to pass a struct with your parameters:

```
struct PrinterParams {
  int a,b,c;
  PrinterParams() : a(0), b(0), c(0) { }
};

void printer(int a, int b, int c) {
 cout << a << endl;
 cout << b << endl;
 cout << c << endl;
}

void printer(const PrinterParams &params) {
  printer(params.a,params.b,params.c);
}


int main(){
  PrinterParams params;

  params.b = 1;
  params.c = 2;
  printer(params);

 return 0;
}
```